# React native Flat list optimization

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to build a contact list in react native. I don't do all the possible optimization that are mentioned in the following mentioned places.

[React native flat list optimization](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration)

[8 ways to optimize React native FlatList performance](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/)

[how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist](https://medium.com/sanjagh/how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist-946490c8c49b)

[How did I optimize my React Native FlatList?](https://medium.com/@giomodiogo/how-did-i-optimize-my-react-native-flatlist-edbc54acc231)

[flatlist-performance-tips](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips)

[react-native-optimized-flatlist](https://github.com/st0ffern/react-native-optimized-flatlist)

I have tried all these one by one. by flat list is too much smooth now. but the only problem is that it takes some time to load initially. I want it like the contact book how has no loading. her ei ma attaching video link how it is behaving.

[my own flat list source code](https://github.com/aftabaminzoobiapps/Optimizedsection_list/blob/main/App.js)

[Video](https://github.com/aftabaminzoobiapps/Optimizedsection_list/blob/main/VID-20210123-WA0003.mp4)

** anyone who can help me to resolve this. I am tired of this and now this becomes a headache for me. help will be really appreciated. ia m trying on this for one month but invain.**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs specifically about the attributes [maxToRenderPerBatch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#maxtorenderperbatch),[updateCellsBatchingPeriod](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#updatecellsbatchingperiod) and [removeClippedSubviews](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#removeclippedsubviews). In your case, it's rendering 50 items per batch of render, the `updateCellsBatchingPeriod` maybe is making the list update itself longer than expected and maybe if you set the prop `removeClippedSubviews` to true the list is going to stay fluid as you want.